# Representing difference between polygons only with Symbology in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, symbology, style, visualisation

In QGIS 3.22 I am trying to visually represent a difference between polygons after its change. In the end I want to know where the polygon was enlarged ([#72ff85](https://www.color-hex.com/color/72ff85)) and where it was degraded ([#ff7272](https://www.color-hex.com/color/ff7272)).

To download data for testing purposes: https://we.tl/t-fqlOCAjLx5 (valid until 16.06.2022)

Let's assume there is a polygon layer called *'master'*, see the image below.

[image: master]

Later on the *'master'* layer was saved as *'branch'* and manually edited, see the image below.

[image: branch]

Hereupon I want to visualize the difference between these two polygon layers. For that purpose I duplicated the *'branch'* layer and applied the following graphical settings:

[image: settings1]

```
sym_difference(
  $geometry,
  geometry(get_feature('master','id',"id"))
  )
```

[image: settings2]

```
if(
    intersects(
        $geometry,
        geometry(get_feature('master','id',"id"))
        ),
    '#ff7272',
    '#72ff85'
    )
```

However, I ended up with nothing meaningful. Seems like the output of the Geometry Generator is a *MultiPolygon* for which the expression does not work.

[image: result_false]

How can I achieve my visual aim just with [Symbology](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html) from the <kbd>Layer Properties</kbd> menu?

I could get the desired result after using several geoalgorithms one after another, namely the ["Symmetrical difference"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#symmetrical-difference) and then the ["Multipart to singleparts"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts). And also applying some settings for the colour:

[image: settings3]

[image: result_true]

So, the reddish colour means that the polygon was degraded, and greenish colour means that it was enlarged.

Comment: Different colours within the same polygon? Nice idea.

Comment: Yes, I want to make these styles as much as possible dynamic. So as soon as a person applies a change in the *'branch'* layer, a new styles set is already there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have Multipart geometries, you must be able to address each part individually. This can be done using the variable [`@geometry_part_num`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#variables) (current geometry part number for feature being rendered), combined with [`geometry_n()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#geometry-n). See below for more detailed explanation.

Then use a [`within()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#within) function and make sure that the parts of your layer *'branch copy'* are really completely within the corresponding feature of the layer *'master'* by applying a small, negative [`buffer()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#buffer).

Use this expression to override color:

```
if(
    within(
        buffer(
            geometry_n($geometry, @geometry_part_num),
            -0.1
            ),
        geometry(
            get_feature('master','id',"id")
            )
        ),
    '#ff7272',
    '#72ff85'
    )
```

[image: settings_true]

and get the output:

[image: result]

**How the above expression works**

When you create symmetrical difference with Geometry Generator on your layer *'branch copy'*, you get Multipart geometries. Using `@geometry_part_num`, each part gets an individual number. Using `geometry_n()`, you can create each part as a separate geometry.

Each of these separate geometries is then checked individually if it is `within` a feature of the layer *'master'*.

Comment: This solution should also work with *MultiPolygons*